# How to add a environment variable to Google AI Notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I would like to include an environment variable on a Google VM which is running a JupyterLab notebook - this variable needs to be present before the notebook is started.

So setting it in the terminal or in the notebook does not work.

I have also tried to modify the bashrc with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an environment variable set up on you Compute Engine instance from boot you might be interested in checking [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Startup scripts are automated tasks that are performed when your instance boots up. To set them it can be done when creating the instance under the **automation** section; if the instance is already created accessing your instance details in the compute engine console and under **custom metadata** clicking on **Add item**.

Steps to create startup scripts can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean google Colab, one solution is using python, for example:

```
import os
os.environ["BASE_DIR"]="/content/drive/MyDrive/"
```